# using initcap function on a json with an list of strings postgresql

Tags: sql, json, string, postgresql, capitalization

I am trying to use the initcap to capitalize the first letter of the string in a list of strings of json type

[image]

The table looks like this.

I tried this first

```
update smfood set category = to_json(string_to_array(INITCAP(category::text),','))
where smfood.category is not null
```

but the results get me these slashes

[image]

any idea on how i can use initcap to capitalize the first letter in a json list of strings?

Comment: It's a better practice to post your sample data and desired results as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
update smfood set category = INITCAP(category::text)::json
where smfood.category is not null;
```